# is (infinitely often p) ∨ (infinitely often ¬p) valid?

Tags: formal-methods, linear-temporal-logic

i'm trying to prove every trace over PROP = {p} is a model of the formula.
I am very stuck in figuring out a model pi that satisfies this formula, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The LTL formula for the given problem could be: $G(F(p)) \lor G(F(\lnot p))$. Consider a $\omega$-word $w = w_1w_2w_3 \ldots$ over $\{\{\}, \{p\}\}$:

Let $w_i = w_iw_{i+1}\ldots$
\begin{align*}
& \; \; \; \; \; \;  \; \; \; w \not\models G(F(p))\\ 
&\implies \exists i . w_i \not\models F(p)\\
&\implies \exists i. \forall j \geq i . w_j \models \lnot p\\ 
&\implies \exists i. \forall j \geq i . w_j \models F(\lnot p)\\ 
&\implies \exists i. w_i \models G(F(\lnot p))\\ 
&\implies w \models G(F(p)) \lor G(F(\lnot p))
\end{align*}

Therefore, $G(F(p)) \lor G(F(\lnot p))$ is valid.

Note that this doesn't mean that $G(F(p)) \land G(F(\lnot p))$ is not satisfiable. For example, consider the word $w=\{p\}\{\}\{p\}\{\}\{p\}\{\}\ldots$

Comment: You're using $w_i$ to mean two different things.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus By convention $w_i \models \psi$ means the first position of $w_i$ satisfies $\psi$. So, can you elaborate why you think I meant two different things by $w_i$...

Comment: You wrote $w_i = w_i w_{i+1} \dots$

Comment: I am still missing where did I use anything other than $w_i = w_iw_{i+1}\ldots$...

Comment: It seems like $w_i$ refers both to the $i$th element of $w$ and to the $i$th shift of $w$.

Comment: When we are talking about $w_i \models \psi $, we mean the first position of $w_i$, which happens to be $i$th position of $w$, satisfies $\psi$. We use the $i$th shift because the formula might contain $X$, $G$... etc operators and hence we need the shift rather than just the $i$th position.

Comment: My only complaint is that $w_i$ signifies both an $\omega$-word and a single state. If this is common in the relevant community, then that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a model $\pi$. Let $T$ be the set of times at which $p$ holds. If $T$ is infinite, then "infinitely often $p$" holds. If $\overline{T}$ is infinite, then "infinitely often $\lnot p$" holds. One of these two must hold, since there are infinitely many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical equivalences to show this is a valid LTL formula over models with the proposition $p \in \mathrm{Prop}$.

$$\begin{aligned}
  &\mathsf{G}\mathsf{F} p \vee \mathsf{G}\mathsf{F}\neg{}p\\
  &= \langle \mathsf{GF}\varphi \vee \mathsf{GF}\psi \equiv \mathsf{G}(\mathsf{F}\varphi \vee \mathsf{F}\psi) \rangle\\
  &\mathsf{G}(\mathsf{F} p \vee \mathsf{F}\neg{}p)\\
  &= \langle \mathsf{F}\varphi \vee \mathsf{F}\psi \equiv \mathsf{F}(\varphi \vee \psi) \rangle\\
  &\mathsf{G}\mathsf{F}( p \vee \neg{}p)\\
  &= \langle\text{excluded middle} + p \in \mathrm{Prop} \rangle\\
  &\mathsf{G}\mathsf{F}\top\\
  &= \langle \mathsf{F}\top \equiv \top \rangle\\
  &\mathsf{G}\top\\
  &= \langle \mathsf{G}\top \equiv \top \rangle\\
  &\top
\end{aligned}$$

Most of the above equivalences are fairly easy to show by unfolding the semantics. The only annoying part is showing the $\mathsf{G}(\mathsf{F} \varphi \vee \mathsf{F}\psi) \Rightarrow \mathsf{G}\mathsf{F} \varphi \vee \mathsf{G}\mathsf{F}\psi$
direction of $\mathsf{G}\mathsf{F} \varphi \vee \mathsf{G}\mathsf{F}\psi \equiv \mathsf{G}(\mathsf{F} \varphi \vee \mathsf{F}\psi)$.

(see also [A Calculational Deductive System for Linear Temporal Logic](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3387109) for a nice list of LTL theorems)